# Aws API Gate Way doesn't create Amazon CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I am following the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) to setup, it says in the doc "**For every API you create, API Gateway sets up an Amazon CloudFront distribution for the API**", I have created 4 API's and deployed them, but when I goto cloudFront, I don't see anything, it says **Create Distribution**. Not sure, What I am missing exactly, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The cloudfront distributions are not exposed to the public. API Gateway internally setups up a cloudfront distribution for every api.

Comment: Thank you, may the following question out of context.  how do i get the arn 
 for cloudfront so that I can set CNAME record for my subdomain ?

Comment: You don't need to get the ARN for the CloudFront distribution. You don't need to care about the fact that API Gateway is using CloudFront behind the scenes. You just need to follow the API Gateway instructions for setting up a custom domain name: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: As @MarkB has mentioned, you should be setting up a custom domain. The CNAME record will be shown when you setup a custom domain.